# How to Navigate / Move Cursor by code block in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to **move the cursor** *(not move the line of code)* in the text editor up a block or down a block by pressing `<ctrl>+<uparrow>` or `<ctrl>+<downarrow>`. In jEdit, Leafpad, etc, this just works out of the box. I do not want to move an entire page at a time, just simply go to the start or end of the text block that I happen to be on.

Specifically, I want this, but for VS 2012 (which no longer has macros):
[keyboard shortcut to move from one code block to another in VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743888/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-from-one-code-block-to-another-in-vs2008)

I've seen these posts, and they **are not** what I'm after; I do not want to move code, I want to move the cursor to the top or bottom of the block I happen to be on.
[Visual Studio: hotkeys to move line up/down and move through recent changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313462/visual-studio-hotkeys-to-move-line-up-down-and-move-through-recent-changes/314064#314064)
[Visual Studio - Scroll AND move cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588127/visual-studio-scroll-and-move-cursor)

I have checked in ReSharper as well, and cannot seem to find an answer there.

Does anyone know of an add-in that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind them to `Edit.PreviousMethod` and `Edit.NextMethod` in the Options->Environment->Keyboard?

Comment: That looked promising, I rebound the keys to that, but it still scrolls, even after restarting VisualStudio :-(

Comment: Hmmm are you sure those keys aren't mapped to something else as well? You can have multiple actions from the same keystroke if you're not careful (testing it myself now)

Comment: Binding those methods to `Ctrl-Alt-Shift Up/Down` works so I'm not sure if it's a case of a clashing keybinding or perhaps that `Ctrl Up/Down` cannot be configured in the editor.

Comment: Yeah I set it on global and tried that. I have ReSharper installed but disabled; when I set the CAS + Up it did nothing, CAS + Down dropped down the class navigator box. I'll play around with it a bit more and see if I can find a conflict in there. Thanks for the suggestion, I think you have me in the right place, I just have to make it work.

Comment: No worries - good luck. For the record, Next/Prev Method in the VB.Net editor (VS2012 Ult) works - it jumps the cursor to the first line of the appropriate method. Interestingly, in C# it seems `Edit.ScrollLineUp/Down` are bound to `CTRL+U/D` butr unbinding them doesn't seem to have solved the problem..

Comment: Cool thanks for the background. I'm writing in c#. I'll try maybe loading VB settings or try a couple other pre-configs and then tweak from there and see if that does it.

Answer (score 2):

I removed everything that was bound to these shortcuts, then bound it to Edit.PreviousMethod and Edit.NextMethod. This put the focus on the method box in the editor, but then you have to press enter to get it to navigate to that method.

The best I could find was using ReSharper, which I was trying to avoid. However, I'm a minimalist and ReSharper got in my way, I was leaving it toggled off almost all the time, so I uninstalled it.

I believe it was ReSharper.MoveToNextMethod or .NavigateToNextMethod, but I have uninstalled it so I'm going on memory. Using it, it would jump to the beginning of the previous or next method, which was not quite what I was looking for, but better than nothing.

**Edit:** I gave up. I moved to .Net Core for c# code and do all my editing outside of Code, using text editors that employ common keyboard shortcuts like Geany, jEdit, etc.